# Enyo 2.4 MVC Architecture

Tags: model-view-controller, enyo

I am working on a application in Enyo which has several submodules, each is having its own model and view. Now among those modules, few modules have data that are same and a sync between those is done using binding which means a change in value of some data affects other module data.

I was thinking to make a common model for shared data and separate model for unique data in each module so that binding cannot play further, thus saving some crucial time. So far I have never seen a view to adapting two models altogether. This raises a question that whether is it possible for a view to have two models altogether?

Is there something in Enyo 2.4 MVC architecture that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you might want to look at using enyo.ModelController.  It will allow you to more easily "swap" a model for a particular component.

Also, you can associate any number of models with a component and bind it up how you like:

```
enyo.kind({
    name: "MyView",
    model: theSharedModel,
    unique: theUniqueModel
    bindings: [...]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that.  Perhaps place your common model onto the App object and your individual view models can live on their respective views.  Bind the shared properties using ".app.sharedModel.property", for example.